# Python: unexpected result when using none

Tags: python, function, if-statement, program-entry-point, nonetype

I thought I understood the none constant as a useful tool to accommodate the absence of parameters.  However, I've encountered scenarios where this doesn't hold, and I don't understand why.

For example:

```
def boxarea(l,w,h):
    if h is not None: 
        area = l*w*h
    else:
        area = l*w
    return area

def main(): 
    a = boxarea(2,3)
    print(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

returns:

```
TypeError: boxarea() missing 1 required positional argument: 'h'
```

Why doesn't this just return 6? Can someone help explain?

Comment: Optional arguments must have default values: `def boxarea(l,w,h=None):`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize h to None if it is not provided as parameter

```
def boxarea(l,w,h=None):
    # your code
```

Comment: Got it.  Has this always been the case?  I've seen old code examples that did not initialize to None.

Comment: I guess you could have seen it in python2, but I am not sure, I am coding only with python3.